# Discord.js — GuildMember.roles.set([]); not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a Discord bot, and I want one of its commands to remove all roles from a member. I ran into an issue, though. Here's the code that I'm using:

```
// Get the ID of either the user mentioned (if the person executing the command has the leader role) or the person executing the command:
var user = (args[0] && args[0].substring(0, 3) === "<@!" && args[0][args[0].length - 1] === ">" && message.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Leader")) ? args[0].substring(3, args[0].length - 1) : message.author.id;
// Remove all of their roles:
message.guild.members.fetch(user).roles.set([]);
```

The console spits out this error:

```
(node:23) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (/app/bot.js:201:48)
    at Client.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/app/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:800:20)
```

It says that it cannot read the property 'set' of undefined (meaning that it either didn't find a user or the '.roles' property doesn't exist; I know it should, as I took the code from [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=set)). I've used the 'var user =' line elsewhere in the code without any problems.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `roles` is undefined, otherwise it would have said `Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined` as the error

Comment: Just blind reading the logic, my assumption would be that `fetch` is performing some sort of asynchronous logic, and `roles` is not a property of the returned promise

Comment: I might have fixed it... testing something right now

Comment: @Taplar .fetch() is asynchronous, I was not aware of this before.

Comment: Yeah, just going off of the name of that method I would have assumed it was, :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `message.guild.members.fetch(user)` is an asynchronous call that returns a Promise.

From the docs (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch):

```
// Fetch a single member
guild.members.fetch('66564597481480192')
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

You'll need to tailor this to your app, but you need to wait for the Promise to resolve before you can set the user's roles.

async/await

```
// Get the ID of either the user mentioned (if the person executing the command has the leader role) or the person executing the command:
var user = (args[0] && args[0].substring(0, 3) === "<@!" && args[0][args[0].length - 1] === ">" && message.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Leader")) ? args[0].substring(3, args[0].length - 1) : message.author.id;
// Remove all of their roles:
const discordUser = await message.guild.members.fetch(user);
discordUser.roles.set([]);
```

then/catch

```
// Get the ID of either the user mentioned (if the person executing the command has the leader role) or the person executing the command:
var user = (args[0] && args[0].substring(0, 3) === "<@!" && args[0][args[0].length - 1] === ">" && message.member.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Leader")) ? args[0].substring(3, args[0].length - 1) : message.author.id;
// Remove all of their roles:
message.guild.members.fetch(user).then((discordUser) => {
  discordUser.roles.set([]);
}).catch((err) => console.log(err)})
```